# How to access entities from many to many relationships

Tags: google-app-engine, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Here is the explanation. I have two entities: House, Person. In my system one person may own multiple houses and one house may have multiple owners. So I create a table (aka entity) called HouseOwnership. I want to be able to make two different kinds of queries against HouseOwnership:

- Given a houseId, get all it's owners
- Given a personId, get all the houses owned

So for HouseOwnership, I do

```
@Entity
class HouseOwnership{
  @Load
  private Ref<House> houseRef;
  @Load
  private Ref<Person> personRef;
}
```

How do I make my queries with `OfyService.ofy()`?

I am tempted to do

```
owners =OfyService.ofy().load().type(HouseOwnership.class).ancestor(house).list()
```

and

```
houses =OfyService.ofy().load().type(HouseOwnership.class).ancestor(person).list()
```

but for this I would have to make both References into `@Parent`. So am I allowed to do that? How do I make the queries?

Also I only have the ids not the actual objects so I would have to create the objects from the ids, which I can do. But I am wondering if there is an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

1. An entity can have only one parent.
2. You don't need to make your HouseOwnership entity a child of any entity.
3. You make a simple query to get all HouseOwnership entities where houseRef property equals a given House key, or personRef property equals a given Person key, or both.
4. You can always make a Key from an ID for entities that have no parents.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to model this as a `@Index Set<Ref<Person>> owners;` property on House. Creating an extra relationship entity creates a significant amount of overhead.

Don't try to map schemas literally from relational models - use the document structure to your advantage.